# gmock matcher doesn't match my arguments by reference

Tags: googlemock, matcher

I have a mocked function in a class like

```
int foo(const bar& b) const;
```

which is mocked like

```
MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(foo, int(const bar& b));
```

for which I've set set some default actions like

```
ON_CALL(anObject, foo(bar(0,0))).WillByDefault(Return(1));
```

My code under test calls

```
anObject.foo(bar(0,0);
```

but instead of returning 1, gmock gives me the following error:

```
Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
Function call: foo(@0xbfffcf90 8-byte object <00-00 00-00 00-00 00-00>)
The mock function has no default action set, and its return type has no default value set.
```

The `operator ==` is defined for the object `bar`. Why can't gmock find my default actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was not in the code above. The `ON_CALL`statement was after the code on test.

Simple answer: **Be sure to have the ON_CALL statements before any code calls the mocked methods.**